# How to add a specific text to columns in a text file in Linux?

Tags: linux

I have a text file containing three columns, I want to add '000'to the end of first and second column. How to do that in Linux?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk '{$1=$1"000"; $2=$2"000"; print}' input.txt
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help :)